# Adjust vertical position of single character in WordPress' Latex

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm trying to define a new operator (like `\bigominus` -- but it doesn't exist) to create an equation like

[image]

But the problem is that I can't shrink the lower indices after vertical aligning everything that follows. The code I have so far is

```
\mathop{\huge{\boldsymbol{\ominus}}}\limits_{\tiny{ijk}}\normalsize{\raisebox{0.7ex}{\text{x}[\,u\,][\,v\,][\,w\,]}}
```

If I remove `\raisebox{0.7ex}{}` it fixes the indices, but then the vertical alignment is gone.

[image]

Obviously it's noticeable with respect to the horizontal line of the symbol. Does anyone know how I may fix this? I would like to either move the `\ominus` symbol down so that the horizontal line is aligned with the cross of the `\text{x}`, or the `\text{x}` and everything that follows so that it aligns with the horizontal line of the `\otimes`.

I've spent a few hours trying to solve this problem but I cannot seem to find the right command in the rather limited available set from WordPress.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale a bold `\ominus`; whether this works in WordPress I don't know, but it would be off-topic, because WordPress uses MathJax that's not TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bigominus}{\DOTSB\bigominus@\slimits@}

\newcommand{\bigominus@}{\mathop{\mathpalette\bigominus@@\relax}}

\newcommand{\bigominus@@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\bigoplus$}%
    \resizebox{\wd\z@}{!}{$\m@th#1\bm{\ominus}$}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\bigominus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\qquad
\textstyle
\bigominus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\qquad
\scriptstyle
\bigominus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\qquad
\scriptscriptstyle
\bigominus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\]
\[
\bigoplus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\qquad
\textstyle
\bigoplus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\qquad
\scriptstyle
\bigoplus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\qquad
\scriptscriptstyle
\bigoplus_{ijk}x[u][v][w]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\bigominus` does exist, in the `mathx` font of the `mathabx` package. You can easily use it without having to change the default math font:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> matha7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigominus}{\mathop}{mathx}{"C1}

\begin{document}

\[ A \bigominus B \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]